# how to program a multi-criteria Access search Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hello i have a problem i want to make a multi-criteria Access search form. i wrote the vba code to select some of the reseach criteria in my database but everytime it show me the error. i don't know exactly what is the error in the syntax that i wrote.

```
'searches parameters according to option criteria
Private Sub txtCherche_Change()
    If Rahmen0 = 1 Then 'search  name in the table Assistenz_Verwaltung
    strRowSource = "SELECT [Name], [Wohnort], [Region]" & "FROM Assistenz_Verwaltung"
                    WHERE [Name] Like "*" & Me.txtCherche.Text & "*"

    ElseIf Rahmen0 = 2 Then 'search Wohnort in the table Assistenz_Verwaltung
    strRowSource = "SELECT [Name], [Wohnort], [Region]" & "FROM Assistenz_Verwaltung"
                    WHERE [Wohnort] Like "*" & Me.txtCherche.Text & "*"

    Else: Rahmen0 = 3 'search Region in the table Assistenz_Verwaltung
    strRowSource = "SELECT [Name], [Wohnort], [Region]" & "FROM Assistenz_Verwaltung"
                    WHERE [Region] Like "*" & Me.txtCherche.Text & "*"

    End If

    lst0.RowSource = strRowSource

End Sub
```

what i expected was that when i choose one of the criteria and write a letter it will select the name or the place or the region according to the letter i chose but it show me the same error messages.

> "Error compiling: Sub or function not defined"

Comment: Looks like you have some issues with quotes around your sql.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are concatenating your string is part of the problem:

```
strRowSource = "SELECT [Name], [Wohnort], [Region]" & "FROM Assistenz_Verwaltung"
                WHERE [Name] Like "*" & Me.txtCherche.Text & "*"
```

That will produce:

```
SELECT [Name], [Wohnort], [Region]FROM Assistenz_VerwaltungWHERE [Name] Like *ChercheStuff*
```

That will not work because you need a space between your SQL keywords like this

```
SELECT [Name], [Wohnort], [Region] FROM Assistenz_Verwaltung WHERE [Name] Like *ChercheStuff*
```

The second problem is that you are not putting quotes around the string you are trying to match (single quotes are easier in this case) - You would want it to look more like this:

```
SELECT [Name], [Wohnort], [Region] FROM Assistenz_Verwaltung WHERE [Name] Like '*ChercheStuff*'
```

In order to achieve that, the code would look more like this:

```
strRowSource = "SELECT [Name], [Wohnort], [Region] FROM Assistenz_Verwaltung WHERE [Name] Like '*" & Me.txtCherche.Text & "*'"
```

See the single quotes within the double quotes? That is important.

Comment: You are aware of the missing`_`(linebreak), `&`(string concatenator) at end of strings first line and`"`in front of Where in second line. If you concat sql-strings in vba, quotes and double-quotes should be escaped (doubled) . Better suggest using a parameter query.

Comment: The missing linebreak causes the error, because compiler looks for a sub/function named`WHERE`, what leads to "Sub or function not defined".

Comment: thanks but i think i wrote it like this the first time i wrote the code and the vba did not accept it so i though i wrote it wrong i will try again thks